# Why is there no specific order on the reputation page?

Tags: discussion, reputation, profile-page

I am looking at my [reputation page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/155556/amanap-lanac-a-nalp-a-nam-a?tab=reputation&sort=post&StartDate=2012-03-28%2019:43:25Z) and I noticed that the history does not seem to be in the correct order:

[image: what is the order]

How are these ordered?

Should they not be ordered by some chronological time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They look to me like posts are ordered by total reputation from greatest to least.

Comment: Yep, you gotta add together the green and red numbers on the side for it to make sense. It also looks like, if two sums are equal (i.e. the +5 and +15/-10), then the one with the most recent activity comes first.

Comment: @Bill hmmmm it seems that this is the case. Thanks for the prompt response ^_^

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Pattern Recognition FTW!  :)

Answer (score 0):

When I select the Time tab I get mine ordered by time, but if I select the Posts tab, they are ordered by total rep (total up the + and the -)

[image]

Guessing that may be your issue - your link certainly goes to a Post-ordered page

Comment: Even so, how is the post page ordered? It does **not** seem to be alphabetical at all.

Comment: That **cannot** be it or else my bounty would be 1st.

Comment: Ahhh - @Bill has it